# how to set small sizes of characters with amsbook class?

Tags: formatting

I know that in with the amsbook documentclass I can use 12pt, 10pt, 8pt options. Is there a way to use 6pt? Is that readable once printed?

Answer (score 1):

`\tiny` makes the font size half of the regular font size. So you could set your font to 12pt and then use `\tiny`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tiny
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

I'll let you decide if it is readable.

Comment: But then, if in the document I have fotontes or something else that call a character-size command, I'll have troubles, no?